# exceeded bandwidth limit with small number of user

Tags: wordpress, web, limit, bandwidth, exceed

I have small number of visitor and my bandwidth is 1000 MB 
and i tried to know the reason  that my site  exceeded the bandwidth but I couldn't figure it out
so can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various tools in cPanel which can be used to monitor the bandwidth used, login to cPanel->under log section-> find the tools like

Latest Visitors,
**Bandwidth**,
Webalizer,
Webalizer FTP,
Raw Access Logs,
Analog Stats,
Error Log,
**AWStats**,
**Resource Usage**

The tools marked in bold are my favorite.

Comment: but how how these can help me ?

Comment: These tools gives the full details of the resources which are eating high band width. for example you have the site with large images/videos/audio/script then find out them and remove or replace them hardly you will get 2 or 3 resources which are causing these issues. Let me know your website url to scan it from my side.

Comment: Thanks that help a lot , my site is blog with small number of image , but i will try what you recommend ,thanks again